# Dojo Build for Rhino and browser environments

Tags: browser, dojo, build-process, rhino

is it possible to have a dojo build that works fine with rhino and browser environments.
I'm in need making server side export of dojo charts and for the server side dojo charts I'm using rhino.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not very specific. The dojo build can run in node.js and rhino environment. But I assume you need a browser to run a dojo application, no matter if it is built into a 'layer' or not. 
Of course -- due to the extensible nature of the dojo build system, you could do some hacks like replacing certain patterns in your code to fix some specific issues. 
Maybe you could be more specific about your scenario.